# Passing JWT Token in SSO

Tags: jwt, sso

I'm in the midst of exploring the concept of Single Sign On with JWT.

[image]

I'm planning to build sso.test.com using Laravel

Referring to chart above, may I know:

- Is it safe to POST JWT token (that consist of user_id) to client (app1.com)?
- Is it appropriate to check "shortExp" and refresh the token every 3 minutes?
- Do we have any security flaw base on above flow?

Thanks!

Comment: the ajax call app1.com -> sso.test.com will not send the cookie (token) because of the same origin policy (since you are setting the cookie on app1.com). How are you checking if the user is already logged in at the sso.test.com?

Comment: on a side note, look up OpenID connect, a protocol that enables SSO.

Comment: @bhorkargbut issit possible send the token in $_POST['token'] from app1.com to sso.test.com? When user are in the same browser, in sso.test.com, we'll validate via session of sso.test.com

i have this idea from the answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532814/single-sign-on-sso-laravel#answer-51691138 , so i'm not sure whether is a good way to implement SSO via JWT

Comment: Yes you can send POST requests in cross domain but you need to configure CORS correctly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). I would still suggest to use standard sso protocols (like OIDC) rather than rolling out your own.

Comment: thanks! well noted on this. appreciate your help so much @bhorkarg!